# `container_of` macro in C++ with the same signature as C's

Tags: c++

I have code that uses the famous `container_of` macro to implement a macro-only linked list library.

It works perfectly in C. Now I want to support C++ on it, so I need a `container_of` replacement for C++ that matches the following signature:

```
container_of(ptr, type, member)
```

The C implementation is this:

```
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) ({ \
            const typeof( ((type *)0)->member ) *__mptr = (ptr); 
            (type *)( (char *)__mptr - offsetof(type,member) );})
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tailored myself a solution. It would be better without templates:

```
template<class P, class M>
size_t my_offsetof(const M P::*member)
{
    return (size_t) &( reinterpret_cast<P*>(0)->*member);
}

template<class P, class M>
P* my_container_of_impl(M* ptr, const M P::*member)
{
    return (P*)( (char*)ptr - my_offsetof(member));
}

#define my_container_of(ptr, type, member) \
     my_container_of_impl (ptr, &type::member)
```

Because, in C, we commonly use `typeof` along with `container_of` to fetch the type of a variable, such as this:

```
typedef struct _AStruct
{
    int data_field;
} AStruct;

AStruct as;
int * ptr = &as.data_field;

my_container_of(ptr, AStruct, data_field);
my_container_of(ptr, typeof(as), data_field);
```

We can provide an extra macro to implement the `typeof` equivalence as well:

```
#include <type_traits>
#define my_typeof(___zarg) std::remove_reference<decltype(___zarg)>::type
```

Comment: `offsetof` is a poor name for a function, since it's a macro in the Standard Library.

Comment: @aschelper It is a nice point, in practice I wouldn't use these common names, but left it "default" for didactic propose. Edited the answer anyways, added `my_` prefix on name to avoid collision.